# Openui5 jquery POST to Node.js Server contains empty request body on server side

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting up a sample App using Openui5 as frontend framework, Node.js & Express.js for backend API and MongoDB as database.
My JQuery Ajax post does not contain any body data when arriving at the backend.

I tried several of the solutions provided on stackoverflow, but none of them seems to work for me. MongoDB and Backend Server are running. Data fetching is also working with ui5 data binding to XML View.

controller.js:

```
    onSave: function () {
        //get user input from local json model
        var oNewEmployee = this.getView().getModel("newEmp").getProperty("/newEmp"),
            data         = JSON.stringify(oNewEmployee),
            url = 'http://localhost:3000/employee';


        //do the post
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data: data,
            type : 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    },
```

server.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/schichtplaner", { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.post("/employee", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I keep getting undefined as output from console. Would be great if someone has an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `body-parser` npm module in order to read the POST request payload.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser